# Liferay Plugin SDK and CVS

Tags: liferay, cvs

To those working with Liferay and the Plugin SDK, the tutorials teach you how to create projects from the Plugin SDK directory.  Unfortunately, this also keeps the project folder inside of the Plugin SDK directory.

My question is, has anyone figured a way to leverage the Plugin SDK but have your project directory anywhere you choose?

This leads to another issue because with everything contained in the Plugin SDK folder, we have to checkin the entire thing in our CVS.  If we didn't do this, then all developers will have to install their Plugin SDK in a controlled manner, and the projects checked out from CVS directly to the Plugin SDK folder.

Any strategies, tips or alternatives are appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using ANT based plugins SDK (which is default when you use Liferay IDE or Developer studio), I used to check in entire Plugins SDK to SVN/CVS at the time of starting the project. The entire development team would then check out the plugins sdk and check in their artifacts in appropriate folders i.e. portlets, hooks, themes, etc. It worked really well for us. The SDK itself doesn't have a big footprint, and it really helps organizing your plugins and building them.

Another approach is to maven-ize them. With this approach you don't have to commit your plugins SDK to CVS/SVN, but it Liferay IDE is not configured with Maven based plugins sdk yet (AFAIK).

You can decide the best approach that suits your needs. Hope this helps!

Comment: Recent release of Liferay IDE supports Liferay Maven projects. Check this blog for more details. https://www.liferay.com/web/gregory.amerson/blog/-/blogs/new-release-liferay-ide-2-0-milestone-1